# angualr ng content does not work with animation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

It only works at first and then the next toggle the opacity is always 1 , any possible ideas or reasosn that causes the issue ? Thanks.

[image]

#html

```
 <div *ngIf="isExpanded" [@fadeInOut]>
    <ng-content select="[Content]"></ng-content>
  </div>
```

#ts

```
  trigger('fadeInOut', [
        state('0, void', style({
            opacity: 0
        })),
        state('1, *', style({
            opacity: 1
        })),
        transition('1 => 0', animate('10ms ease-out')),
        transition('0 => 1', animate('100ms ease-in')),
        transition('void <=> *', animate('200ms ease-in'))
    ]),
```

Comment: @fadeInOut is applied for the div that doesn't change its state. I am not very sure what you are trying to do, but at least pass something as a param, that chagnes `[@fadeInOut]="SometimesOneSometimesTwo"`

Comment: can I pass the isExpanded as a param ?

Comment: should the logic be opposite to the toggle ? like if toggle is true then animation value should be false?

Comment: as I see your states are described as 1 and as 2. it should change between 1 and 2